# Authorization fails with - "An error occured while fetching client info"

Tags: nest-api

Has anyone encountered a problem with Oauth2 authorization that started in the past few hours?

When performing an authorization flow, the initial POST call 'https://home.nest.com/login/oauth2/....' returns with the following error on the `Works with Nest` window.

[image: see screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

There was a temporary issue with authenticating new clients. It was a bug on the Nest side and not from anything you did.

It has since been fixed.